# Trying to Add Registrar DNSSEC Records, - Need Some Guidance, Please

Tags: bind, registrar

I have created DNSSEC records for my domain using an old guide from serverfault.com [ https://serverfault.com/questions/405528/basic-dnssec-configuration-under-bind-9-7 ] and I would now like to add my DNSSEC details to my domain registrar's records, but I am a bit stuck on what to put where in their table.

**Keytag:**    I have a **keyid** in my public key file, so would this be it?

**Algorithm:** I know this to be **5**.

**Digest Type:** I know this to be **RSASHA1**.

**Digest:**      Not sure: I have tested various strings from the files, where I could be sure that the strings were public, not private, but I keep on seeing the same error: **ERROR:** *Parameter value range error*

Can anyone enlighten me on this, please?

...

**Ready for Confusion link:** http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on registry, the information you need to provide will exactly correspond to either a DNSKEY record (for .eu) or to a DS record (most other registries). Since you're being asked for a "digest", that means DS.

That means you can short-circuit this by skipping to the "Digest" section below, generating a DS record from your key (or zone), and copy/pasting all the fields straight from it.

The individual fields are:

**Key tag:** Same as keyid. DS records have a key tag that's a 5-digit (or sometimes 4-digit; generally 16-bit) number (based on a hash of the whole key). If your generated key files were named `Kexample.com.+005+12345.key`, the key tag is 12345. It will be shown in the `dnssec-dsfromkey` output too.

**Algorithm:** In your zone it's `5` for RSASHA1.

**Digest Type:** That's definitely *not* RSASHA1. It could be either `1` for SHA1 or `2` for SHA256, but it doesn't depend on the zone itself: it just indicates what sort of hash you'll be giving in the following field. It's common to add DS records with both hash types for the same key.

**Digest:** This cannot be taken directly from your key files; it can be *generated* from them, using such tools as `dnssec-dsfromkey` or `ldns-key2ds`:

```
$ dnssec-dsfromkey Kexample.com+005+12345.key

$ dig example.com. dnskey @::1 | dnssec-dsfromkey -A -f - example.com.
```

(The `-A` flag is needed because you don't have any ZSKs, i.e. keys with the SEP flag set. While technically valid, this can cause much annoyance due to tools skipping non-SEP keys.)

By default the command will show two DS records using different hashes; you can add both or whichever you want. If you chose RSASHA1 because you aim for best compatibility *(which I'd believe if you supported IPv4)*, then you should include the SHA1 DS record as well. Otherwise, SHA256 is also widely supported already.

Comment: SUCCESS: Command completed successfully! - Absolutely perfect answer, - thanks!